# Is there a module for user level permissions?

Tags: 7

I know that permissions are controlled by admins. I want regular users to control a different set of permissions, for example my users will have pictures, friends list, personal information in there profile. I want them to be able to create groups and limit access so certain groups can see certain content. Is there a module for this or do I need to put on by big boy paints and start coding?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Check out the [Role Delegation](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_delegation) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> ... allows site administrators to grant some roles the authority to assign selected roles to users, without them needing the administer permissions permission.

Comment: This is a good module but it's not quite what I'm looking for. To get the results I'm looking for I may need to create a module for each thing that needs to have user permissions on and integrate it with my own user permissions module. Facebook security settings very closely resembles what I'm trying to accomplish where you can limit certain content to friends only or everyone or friends of a certain category.

Comment: Oh. Perhaps you should just check out Organic Groups then. I believe it has that sort of security separation built in.

http://drupal.org/project/og